# Recycler View Item Gone is not working properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to hide part of my view in recycler when user toggles switch. 
But when i toggle switch, sometimes it behaves in a strange way and hides only part of my view. It happens every 4 switch clicks (show-hide-show-hide), and i can't manage to solve this bug. Any advices what am i doing wrong?
There are screenshots of [properly displayed view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MoEh.png) and [awkwardly hidden view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rldyb.png). As you can see, at the second screenshot seekbar with 2 image views is not fully hidden.
UPDATED: The problem is solved. Problem was in include tag. It somehow works wrong, the same layout in item file works fine.

Here is code for hiding logic:

```
itemView.light_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            itemView.brightness.visibility = if (isChecked) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            lightCallback(lamp, isChecked)
        }
```

And here is my layout (recycler item):

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:background="#1a1a1a">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/light_icon_image_view"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/prod_foot" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/light_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/light_icon_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/light_icon_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/light_icon_image_view"
        tools:text="Floodlight 24 368 (01)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="No group"
        android:textColor="#7fffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/light_name_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/light_name_text_view" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/light_switch"
        style="@style/SwitchCompatStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/light_icon_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/light_icon_image_view"
        app:thumbTint="@android:color/white" />


    <include
        android:id="@+id/brightness"
        layout="@layout/brightness_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/light_icon_image_view">

    </include>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/light_gradient_circle"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/light_icon_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/light_icon_image_view"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/badge_color_wheel_active_block" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Include layout is provided below (seekbar with 2 images):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#1a1a1a"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/seekbar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dim_min" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:max="255"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/seekbar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dim_max" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

UPDATED: Adapter full code

```
class IndividualLightsAdapter(private val context: Context,
                              private val data: MutableList<Lamp>,
                              private val lightCallback: (Lamp, Boolean) -> Unit,
                              private val lightBrightnessCallback: (lamp: Lamp, brightness: Int) -> Unit)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<IndividualLightsAdapter.LightViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LightViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.light_item_new, parent, false)
        return LightViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LightViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(position)
    }

    inner class LightViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val lamp = data[position]
            itemView.light_icon_image_view.setImageResource(lamp.imageId)
            itemView.light_name_text_view.text = lamp.customName

            itemView.light_gradient_circle.visibility = if (lamp is SmartLamp) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE

            itemView.light_switch.isChecked = lamp.isTurnedOn

            itemView.light_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                itemView.brightness.visibility = if (isChecked) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
                lightCallback(lamp, isChecked)
            }

            setSeekBar()

            itemView.seekbar.progress = lamp.brightness
            itemView.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                    lightBrightnessCallback(lamp, progress)
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                }

                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                }
            })

        }


        private fun setSeekBar() {

            val gradient = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
                    intArrayOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.grad_start), (ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.grad_end))))
            gradient.cornerRadius = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.corner_radius_outer)

            val progressLayer = ClipDrawable(gradient, Gravity.START, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL)

            val background = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, intArrayOf(Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK))
            background.cornerRadius = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.corner_radius_inner)

            // TODO Calculate padding dynamically

            val backgroundLayer = InsetDrawable(background,
                    context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.padding_inset_left).toInt(),
                    context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.padding_inset_top).toInt(),
                    context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.padding_inset_right).toInt(),
                    context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.padding_inset_bottom).toInt())


            itemView.seekbar.thumb.setTint((ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_thumb)))

            itemView.seekbar.progressDrawable = LayerDrawable(arrayOf<Drawable>(backgroundLayer, progressLayer))

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the adapter code and the code for lightCallback(lamp, isChecked). Is this the only place the where the visibility is set / changed?

Comment: @Juan see updated code. Callback is mocked (it just logs some info)

Comment: Please: Debug and check at runtime if the itemView.brightness layout you are picking up is the correct one. If it is, invalidate the view after setting it to GONE or VISIBLE.

Comment: @Juan i managed to fix the problem. I removed <include> and written the same layout but in my item file. Idk what was the problem, but it works

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't hide the view that is an item of recyclerView.

It doesn't work properly because of its recycling mechanism.

You just need to remove/add the item to be able to do the same effect.

you should has the below methods on your `RecyclerView adapter`

```
   private void deleteItem(int position) {
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            myList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    private void addItem(int position, MyModel model) {
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            myList.add(position, model);
            notifyItemInserted(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not adding/removing item. That's all only in one item, I'm changing part of itemView visibility. Sorry for question name confuse.